# Separating XML text into three separate blocks

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where I need to split the following Text into three separate XML blocks
A needs to be one block, B another block and C another block.

```
<line cnt="16"><![CDATA[                         A               B         C]]></line>
    <line cnt="17"/>
    <line cnt="18"><![CDATA[TOTAL               2583000            0      4800000]]></line>
    <line cnt="19"/>
    <line cnt="20"><![CDATA[06:00 - 07:00        ValueA            ValueB   ValueC]]></line>
    <line cnt="21"><![CDATA[07:00 - 08:00        ValueA            ValueB   ValueC]]></line>
    <line cnt="22"><![CDATA[08:00 - 09:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="23"><![CDATA[09:00 - 10:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="24"><![CDATA[10:00 - 11:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="25"><![CDATA[11:00 - 12:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="26"><![CDATA[12:00 - 13:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="27"><![CDATA[13:00 - 14:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="28"><![CDATA[14:00 - 15:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="29"><![CDATA[15:00 - 16:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="30"><![CDATA[16:00 - 17:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="31"><![CDATA[17:00 - 18:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="32"><![CDATA[18:00 - 19:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="33"><![CDATA[19:00 - 20:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="34"><![CDATA[20:00 - 21:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="35"><![CDATA[21:00 - 22:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="36"><![CDATA[22:00 - 23:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="37"><![CDATA[23:00 - 00:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="38"><![CDATA[00:00 - 01:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="39"><![CDATA[01:00 - 02:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="40"><![CDATA[02:00 - 03:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="41"><![CDATA[03:00 - 04:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="42"><![CDATA[04:00 - 05:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="43"><![CDATA[05:00 - 06:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
```

An example of the outcoming block needs to be

```
<Block>
<Contract ContractID="xxx"/>
<Location CodeAgency="xxx" LocID="A" LocQualifier="xxx"/>
<DataSeries ValueType="xxx" ValueQualifier="xxx" ValueUnit="xxx" ValueInterval="xxx">
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T04:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T00:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T00:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T01:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T01:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T02:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T02:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T03:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T03:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T04:00:00Z"/>
</DataSeries>
</Block>
<Block>
<Contract ContractID="xxx"/>
<Location CodeAgency="xxx" LocID="B" LocQualifier="xxx"/>
<DataSeries ValueType="xxx" ValueQualifier="xxx" ValueUnit="xxx" ValueInterval="xxx">
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T04:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T00:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T00:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T01:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T01:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T02:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T02:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T03:00:00Z"/>
<Data Value="ValueB" TimeFrom="2019-10-12T03:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-12T04:00:00Z"/>
</DataSeries>
</Block>
<Block>
<Contract ContractID="xxx"/>
<Location CodeAgency="xxx" LocID="C" LocQualifier="xxx"/>
<DataSeries ValueType="xxx" ValueQualifier="xxx" ValueUnit="xxx" ValueInterval="xxx">
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T00:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T00:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T01:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T01:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T02:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T02:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T03:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T03:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T04:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T04:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueC" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z"/>
</Block>
```

I am trying to adapt the following XSLT coding, this is a snippet more can be shown upon request. The main difficulty for me is creating code that will separate the Location IDs and their corresponding hourly values into the blocks.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
        <xsl:variable name="from">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//line[contains(translate(text(), $uppercase, $smallcase),'period:')]/text(),':'),'-'))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="to">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after(//line[contains(translate(text(), $uppercase, $smallcase),'period:')]/text(),':'),'-'))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="auction">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//line[contains(text(),'successful participation in the following auction')]">true</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>         
        </xsl:variable>
    <OwnerId>
                        <xsl:variable name="lineId">
                            <xsl:value-of select="//line[contains(translate(text(),$uppercase, $smallcase), 'the bid was placed by:') or contains(translate(text(),$uppercase, $smallcase), 'the capacity was booked by:')]/@cnt + 1"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains(//line[@cnt=$lineId]/text(),'Shell Energy')">
                                <xsl:value-of select ="2"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select ="1"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </OwnerId>
                    <DealId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(translate(//line[contains(translate(text(), $uppercase, $smallcase),'deal id:')]/text(),'/',' '),':'))"/>
                    </DealId>
                    <xsl:variable name="NB_Booking">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(//line[contains(translate(text(), $uppercase, $smallcase),'tso:')]/text(),':'))"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <NetpointId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($NB_Booking,' '),'#',normalize-space(substring-after(//line[contains(translate(text(), $uppercase, $smallcase),'id of network point:')]/text(),':')))"/>
                    </NetpointId>
                    <Direction>
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(substring-after(//line[contains(translate(text(), $uppercase, $smallcase),'direction:')]/text(),':')),'e','E')"/>
                    </Direction>
                    <DayAhead>
                        <!-- wenn milliseconds fuer addhour(from) = milliseconds fuer to dann true-->
                                                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="ut:getTimeStamp(ut:addDay($from,1,1,1),4) = ut:getTimeStamp($to,1)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                    </DayAhead>
```

Comment: It seems that the `line` elements contain fixed-width data - so it should be trivial to extract any portion using the `substring()` function. Not sure where exactly you are stuck with this. The XSLT you show does not seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Understood so the XSLT I've displayed is for something we have used before, I thought it might be useful. How would I go about this from scratch I've created the header I just need the block coding

Comment: I posted an answer showing how to extract the individual values. It does not handle bumping up the date at midnight or creating "separate blocks" (not sure what that means exactly). I suggest you post additional questions separately if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <line cnt="20"><![CDATA[06:00 - 07:00        ValueA            ValueB   ValueC]]></line>
    <line cnt="21"><![CDATA[07:00 - 08:00        ValueA            ValueB   ValueC]]></line>
    <line cnt="22"><![CDATA[08:00 - 09:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="23"><![CDATA[09:00 - 10:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="24"><![CDATA[10:00 - 11:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="25"><![CDATA[11:00 - 12:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="26"><![CDATA[12:00 - 13:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="27"><![CDATA[13:00 - 14:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="28"><![CDATA[14:00 - 15:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="29"><![CDATA[15:00 - 16:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="30"><![CDATA[16:00 - 17:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="31"><![CDATA[17:00 - 18:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="32"><![CDATA[18:00 - 19:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="33"><![CDATA[19:00 - 20:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="34"><![CDATA[20:00 - 21:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="35"><![CDATA[21:00 - 22:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="36"><![CDATA[22:00 - 23:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="37"><![CDATA[23:00 - 00:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="38"><![CDATA[00:00 - 01:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="39"><![CDATA[01:00 - 02:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="40"><![CDATA[02:00 - 03:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="41"><![CDATA[03:00 - 04:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="42"><![CDATA[04:00 - 05:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
    <line cnt="43"><![CDATA[05:00 - 06:00        107625            0       200000]]></line>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="date">2019-10-11</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="line">
            <Data Value="{normalize-space(substring(., 22, 18))}">
                <xsl:attribute name="TimeFrom">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
                    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 5)"/>
                    <xsl:text>:00Z</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="TimeTo">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
                    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 9, 5)"/>
                    <xsl:text>:00Z</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="ValueA" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T07:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T08:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T09:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T10:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T11:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T12:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T13:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T14:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T15:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T16:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T17:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T18:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T19:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T20:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T21:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T22:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T23:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T00:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T00:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T01:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T01:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T02:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T02:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T03:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T03:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T04:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T04:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z"/>
  <Data Value="107625" TimeFrom="2019-10-11T05:00:00Z" TimeTo="2019-10-11T06:00:00Z"/>
</result>
```

Comment: How would I then be able to duplicate the blocks for value B and Value C

Comment: By adding two more `<xsl:for-each select="line">` blocks? I can't give you a definite answer without seeing the expected result - see: [mcve].

Comment: I've added the complete results

Comment: I see no change in your question.

Comment: Okay I've changed it now sorry I tried to edit your answer instead of my question

Comment: As I said, just repeat the same `xsl:for-each` instruction and change the `start` and `length` arguments in the `Value` attribute template.

Comment: you've used substring(., 22, 18), but where is the . in the text?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how that can give me the correct value if I'm correct, this starts at character 22 and should output 18 places, however that is not the case. Can you break this line down? "{normalize-space(substring(., 22, 18))}">

Comment: `.` means the current node, which is `line` in this case, because we are in `<xsl:for-each select="line">`. `substring(., 22, 18)` extracts 18 characters starting from position 22. `normalize-space()` removes the trailing spaces.

Comment: if the value changes from 107625 to for example 50, is there any way to make it dynamic

Comment: I have said from the beginning that I assume the input is in a fixed-width format. If my assumption is correct, then the value of `50` will be represented by the string `"50"` followed by 16 spaces. When you extract these 18 characters and apply `normalize-space()` to the extracted substring, you will end up with `50`.